# $l_1$ equipped with the sup norm is NOT a Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Prove that $l_1 = \{ x = (x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{R};\ \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\ |x_k| < +\infty \}$ equipped with the norm
$\| x\| = \mathrm{sup}_{k\in\mathbb{N}} |x_k|$ is NOT a Banach Space.

I've tried to solve it considering the sequence
$x_n = (\frac{1}{k^{1 + 1/n}}),\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Since $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{k^{1 + 1/n}} < +\infty$ (because $1+1/n > 1$), $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $l_1$. We also have that $x_n \longrightarrow (1/k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}},$ as $n\longrightarrow +\infty$, and this one is not in $l_1$.

I would like to prove that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence, but I don't have a clue how to do it.

Comment: Well $x_n \to (1/k)_{k \in N}$ in $l^\infty$, and any convergent sequence is Cauchy....

Comment: I thought it maybe help, but the definition of convergence does not assume the limit is also in same metric space the sequence is? If we consider the closure $\overline{l_1}$, then $x_n\to (1/k)_k$ in $\overline{l_1}$ and then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\overline{l_1}$. Does it imply that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $l_1$?

Comment: Yes, . So $\{x_n\}_n$ convergent in $\overline{l_1}$ implies $\{x_n\}_n$ Cauchy in $\overline{ l_1}$. If you write what this means, you'll see that only the norm matters, the limit and space are irrelevant...

Comment: A late comment now but I don't see immediately why from $x_n\to(1/k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ as $x\to\infty$, we can deduce that $(x_n)$ not in $\mathscr{l}^1$ because the Algebraic Limit Theorem applies only to a finite number of terms.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let me propose you an example I find easier.

So $\ell^\infty$ is a Banach space with the sup norm, and $\ell^1$ is a subspace of $\ell^\infty$. Hence what you want boils down to: **$\ell^1$ is not closed in $\ell^\infty$**.

For every $n\geq 1$, consider the finitely supported sequence
$$
x^{(n)}=\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{n},0,\ldots\right).
$$
Clearly, every $x^{(n)}$ is in $\ell^1$. It is also easy to see that $x^{(n)}$ converges to 
$$
x=\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k+1},\ldots\right)
$$
in $\ell^\infty$, for the sup norm.

But $x$ is not in $\ell^1$ as the harmonic series diverges. So $\ell^1$ is not closed in $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: pretty much easier! Thanks!

Comment: @mateusakio You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x_n$ be any sequence that converges to zero, but $\sum_n |x_n| = \infty$.

Let $[y_k]_n = \begin{cases} x_n & n \le k \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Then $y_k \in l_1$ for all $k$, and $y_k$ is a Cauchy sequence (in the $l_\infty$ norm). Since $l_\infty$ is complete, $y_k$ converges to some $y \in l_\infty$ (it is easy to see that $[y]_n = x_n$), but clearly $y \notin l_1$.

Comment: In other terms, $c_0\setminus\ell^1$ is contained in $\overline{\ell^1}\setminus \ell^1$. Actually, since $c_0$ is closed in $\ell^\infty$, this is an equality: $c_0\setminus\ell^1=\overline{\ell^1}\setminus \ell^1$. Now you get a pretty good description of how far $\ell^1$ is from being closed.

Comment: @julien: Nice observation. We have $\overline{l_1} = c_0$ (in $l_\infty$).